# Launcher and Dock

Tags: 18.04, launcher, ubuntu-dock

Have just updated my computer from Ubuntu 16 LTS to Ubuntu 18 LTS and the original Launcher is still there with the new "Dock" super-imposed over each other.  How does one get rid of the original launcher so it doesn't interfer with the new OS??  I have relocated the "Dock" to the bottom of the window but the Launcher is still on the left but inoperative.

Gary

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? And have you installed by any chance the dash to dock extension?

Comment: I got the local tech to get rid of the old Launcher bar but now I can't set the window resolution---it is at the 4 X 3 locked in it seems and found no way to change it---need it to be a 16 X 9 or close to that.